# Run make files for different directories and save

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, directory

I am new in bash scripting, trying to create a bash script where: I run a make file several times and then I save the results in different directories, so the first time I run the code, I want to save the results to `dir_1`, the second time to `dir_2`, etc.

My script for now is:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in ~/bin/*/
do

dir=${dir%*/}
echo ${dir##*/}

starnvt

done
```

What should I add/change?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having with your code?

Comment: Actually, I tried some things and now I think that I have something more "well-written".                                                #!/bin/bash
j=1 
while [ $j -le 5 ] 
do
cd run_dir_$j
starnvt;
cd ..
# echo "run_dir_$j"
j=$(( $j + 1))
done`                                                                 But now it runs the starnvt makefile only for the first subdir (run_dir_1) and saves the results in this one, but then does not run it for the other directories.